# How to measure wallclock time in C++ instead of cpu time?

Tags: c++, time

I would like to measure wallclock time taken by my algorithm in C++. Many articles point to this code.

```
clock_t begin_time, end_time;
begin_time = clock();
Algorithm();
end_time = clock();
cout << ((double)(end_time - begin_time)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << endl;
```

But this measures only cpu time taken by my algorithm.
Some other article pointed out this code.

```
double getUnixTime(void)
{
    struct timespec tv;

    if(clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tv) != 0) return 0;

    return (tv.tv_sec + (tv.tv_nsec / 1000000000.0));
}
double begin_time, end_time;
begin_time = getUnixTime();
Algorithm();
end_time = getUnixTime();
cout << (double) (end_time - begin_time) << endl;
```

I thought it would print wallclock time taken by my algorithm. But surprisingly, the time printed by this code is much lower than cpu time printed by previous code. So, I am confused. Please provide code for printing wallclock time.

Comment: Can you give example output of the two bits of code showing the problem?

Comment: Can you use C++11?  If so, check out [`<chrono>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz For my algorithm, the first code outputs 3.2034e-06, where as the second code outputs 4.59695e-07

Comment: You're going to have to repeat your algorithm many times until it gets to a long enough period to be accurately measured by these, and then you'll still have to wonder if it was caching, or if you just got lucky/unlucky with the OS scheduling different things at the same time. Also benchmark it multiple times to average this out.

Comment: Those times are so small the difference could just be the extra time the floating point division takes in the `getUnixTime` function. At a minimum, you need to measure the time an empty algorithm takes (one that does nothing) and subtract that if you want to have any hope of accurately measuring times that small.

Comment: I ran the algorithm 100000 times. Now, the first code shows 0.041544s whereas the second code shows 0.0424559s

Comment: So basically the same. Which makes sense if you're running the same algorithm and same data.

Answer (score 2):

Those times are probably down in the noise. To get a reasonable time measurement, try executing your algorithm many times in a loop:

```
const int loops = 1000000;
double begin_time, end_time;
begin_time = getUnixTime();

for (int i = 0; i < loops; ++i)
    Algorithm();

end_time = getUnixTime();
cout << (double) (end_time - begin_time) / loops << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting approximately the same times in a single threaded program:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
__attribute((noinline)) void nop(void){}
void loop(unsigned long Cnt) { for(unsigned long i=0; i<Cnt;i++) nop(); }
int main()
{
    clock_t t0,t1;
    struct timespec ts0,ts1;
    t0=clock();
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&ts0);
    loop(1000000000);
    t1=clock();
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&ts1);
    printf("clock-diff: %lu\n", (unsigned long)((t1 - t0)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
    printf("clock_gettime-diff: %lu\n", (unsigned long)((ts1.tv_sec - ts0.tv_sec)));
}
//prints 2 and 3 or 2 and 2 on my system
```

But `clock`s manpage only describes it as returning an *approximation*. There's no indication that approximation is comparable to what `clock_gettime` returns.

Where I get drastically different results is where I throw in multiple threads:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
__attribute((noinline)) void nop(void){}
void loop(unsigned long Cnt) {
    for(unsigned long i=0; i<Cnt;i++) nop();
}
void *busy(void *A){ (void)A; for(;;) nop(); }
int main()
{
    pthread_t ptids[4]; 
    for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof(ptids)/sizeof(ptids[0]); i++)
        pthread_create(&ptids[i], 0, busy, 0);
    clock_t t0,t1;
    struct timespec ts0,ts1;
    t0=clock();
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&ts0);
    loop(1000000000);
    t1=clock();
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&ts1);
    printf("clock-diff: %lu\n", (unsigned long)((t1 - t0)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
    printf("clock_gettime-diff: %lu\n", (unsigned long)((ts1.tv_sec - ts0.tv_sec)));

}
//prints 18 and 4 on my 4-core linux system
```

That's because both musl and glibc on Linux use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &ts)` to implement `clock()` and the `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` nonstandard clock is described in the `clock_gettime` manpage as returning time for all process threads together.